# Regex conditional not returning false on the minimum underscores

Tags: c#, regex, string, alphanumeric

I am using this RegEx in if RegEx is match

```
 if (Regex.IsMatch(_familyname, @"(\S*_){3}\S"))
```

I tried to ensure that the word passing the test had at least this
Word1_Word2_WORD3-maybe_Word4 (note hyphens or spaces within are word are not important)
The RegEx `(\S*_){3}\S` allows a word with two underscores to pass also.
Is there a RegEx match for only three underscores and any word/character/symbol is allowed between these underscores? Oh also it never ends or starts with an underscore either. Also if a test that the third alphanumeric string was all capitals would be great. Actually I achieved all this using string split. However I read RegEx can be faster? Also using .NET 4.5.2

Comment: Actually, I believe this can be made simpler, but the question is unclear. Please provide examples of all possible types of input with 1 or 2 strings that should not match and explain why they are (in)valid.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had to add another regex conditional to prevent users creating a name with 4 underscores, this prevents the most common error, they might add more so it's not the most elegant solution, besides it might run slower than a solution that uses one regex statement. Thanx Mageos for the greedy, lazy and possessive tutorial, I used + to get less matches using regex storm so I am guessing that this is a quicker method than I had before.

Regex.IsMatch( *familyname, @"(\S+*){3}\S")
&! Regex.IsMatch(*familyname, @"(\S+*){4}\S")

Comment: It is not quite clear what you need to do here: return *true* for `Word1_Word2_WORD3-maybe_Word4` and *false* for `Word1_Word2_WORD3-maybe_Word4_Word5`? Try `@"(?<![_\S])[^\s_]+(?>_[^\s_]+){3}(?!_)"`

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Comment: Thanx for the effort wiktor, i am currently at a conferecne i will get back to you soon and let you know if this works

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is "greedy"  Try this one:

if (Regex.IsMatch(*familyname, @"(\S*?*){3}\S"))

For more information see:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to validate a string that contains a chunks of non-whitespace characters that has exactly 3 underscores in it. The main issue here is that `\S` matches an underscore, too, that is why you actually need `[^\s_]` construct - a negated character class matching any char but a whitespace and `_`.

Next, you want to make sure the starting point for a match is not preceded with a non-whitespace (it also includes `_`), so, you need a negative lookbehind `(?<!\S)`.

And finally, since you need to make sure there is no `_` after a 4th chunks of chars other than whitespace and underscore, you need to use an *atomic group* (since there is no possessive quantifiers in .NET regex) to prevent backtracking into the `[^\s_]+` pattern (i.e. to only check if there is no `_` after the last char matched with `[^\s_]` once).

Use

```
var res = Regex.IsMatch(str, @"(?<!\S)[^\s_]+(?>_[^\s_]+){3}(?!_)");
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5CS%29%5B%5E%5Cs_%5D%2B%28%3F%3E_%5B%5E%5Cs_%5D%2B%29%7B3%7D%28%3F!_%29&i=Word1_Word2_WORD3-maybe_Word4%20%20Word1_Word2_WORD3%20Word1_Word2_WORD3-maybe_Word4_Word5)

**Details**:

- `(?<!\S)` - a negative lookbehind making sure there is no non-whitespace char immediately to the left of the current location
- `[^\s_]+` - 1+ chars other than whitespace and `_`
- `(?>`  - start of an atomic group

  - `_` - an underscore
  - `[^\s_]+` - 1+ chars other than whitespace and `_`
- `){3}` - repeat matching the contents of  the atomic group 3 times exactly
- `(?!_)` - check once if there is a `_` immediately to the right and if it is there, fail the match, else, return the match.

Also, note you might just split a string and then check if any of the chunks contain exactly 3 `_` chars with a mere:

```
var str = "Word1_Word2_WORD3-maybe_Word4  Word1_Word2_WORD3 Word1_Word2_WORD3-maybe_Word4_Word5";
var res = str.Split().Any(s => s.Count(f => f == '_') == 3);
Console.WriteLine(res ? "Valid" : "Invalid");
```

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/AjzLvM).